In Microsoft SQL server need to update if value is null need to update previous data available in table
In Microsoft SQL server need to update if value is null need to update previous data available in table.
For example:



Column1
column2
column3




91
1006
-46


Null
NUll
77


NUll
Null
-67


87
677
56


Null
null
56



In this table need to update 2 and 3 row column1 as 91 and column 2 as 1006 and for 5 row column 1 as 87 and column 2 as 677
but there is no unique column or compare column like date or any column

From your description, you have a heap table. The data does not have any defined order, so the concept of "the previous row" makes no sense. You can only have a previous row if you can specify a sort order for the data.
